# Find the PDF $f_Y(y)$ for a random variable $Y = X^n$ 

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. Assume a random variable $Y=X^n$, where $n$ is a fixed number. Please find the probability density function for the random variable $Y$; i.e., $f_Y (y)$?.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as far as formulas go for this? I'm kind of lost on how to start, and the book I have right now is not helping a single bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these problems, it may be easier to manipulate the cumulative distribution function (CDF) first.

Notice that $Y$ is also supported on $(0,1)$.* Let's calculate its CDF. Fix $y \in (0,1)$. Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_Y(y) 
= \Pr[Y \leqslant y]
= \Pr[X^n \leqslant y]
= \Pr[0 \leqslant X \leqslant y^{1/n}]
= F_X(y^{1/n})
= y^{1/n},
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
since $F_X(z) = z$ for $0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1$. Can you calculate the PDF of $Y$ from here?

---

*I am assuming that $n$ is a positive integer.